# Is there a way to set singular/plural labels for taxonomy term names?

Tags: taxonomy, terms, labels

Let's says I have a taxonomy called Types. I know I can have a singular name when registering the taxonomy... so I could just set the singular label to Type.

But is there a way to the same/similar to the actual terms inside Type?

Eg.
Term / Plural / Singular
Books -> Book
Movies -> Movie

Will I need a custom field? Or is there a Wp way of doing this?

Comment: Personally I've hacked it using the desciption field.

Comment: Yeah.. I guess there's no way. I am already using the description field, but I can add a custom field.

Answer (score 2):

In WordPress 4.4 we will be able to use the long waited *term meta* so you might use that to store the extra info for your terms.

The Term Meta API calls are:

**Add term meta**:

Function call:

```
add_term_meta( $term_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique );
```

Description:

```
/**
 * Adds metadata to a term.
 *
 * @since 4.4.0
 *
 * @param int    $term_id    Term ID.
 * @param string $meta_key   Metadata name.
 * @param mixed  $meta_value Metadata value.
 * @param bool   $unique     Optional. Whether to bail if an entry with the same key is found for the term.
 *                           Default false.
 * @return int|WP_Error|bool Meta ID on success. WP_Error when term_id is ambiguous between taxonomies.
 *                           False on failure.
 */
```

**Update term meta**:

Function call:

```
update_term_meta( $term_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value );
```

Description:

```
/**
 * Updates term metadata.
 *
 * Use the `$prev_value` parameter to differentiate between meta fields with the same key and term ID.
 *
 * If the meta field for the term does not exist, it will be added.
 *
 * @since 4.4.0
 *
 * @param int    $term_id    Term ID.
 * @param string $meta_key   Metadata key.
 * @param mixed  $meta_value Metadata value.
 * @param mixed  $prev_value Optional. Previous value to check before removing.
 * @return int|WP_Error|bool Meta ID if the key didn't previously exist. True on successful update.
 *                           WP_Error when term_id is ambiguous between taxonomies. False on failure.
 */
```

**Delete term meta**:

Function call:

```
delete_term_meta( $term_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )
```

Description:

```
/**
 * Removes metadata matching criteria from a term.
 *
 * @since 4.4.0
 *
 * @param int    $term_id    Term ID.
 * @param string $meta_key   Metadata name.
 * @param mixed  $meta_value Optional. Metadata value. If provided, rows will only be removed that match the value.
 * @return bool True on success, false on failure.
 */
```

Comment: Will 4.4 have an UI for it?

Comment: at least not like the custom fields UI  for posts, afaik, but adding a custom term UI shouldn't be a major issue ;-) Here's the now closed trac ticket [#10142](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10142) @gdaniel